# What is the full form of Rd, Rn, Rm, Ra in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, arm

We use these terms very often. But why are they named so is not clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do the abbriviations (Rn, Rd, ...) in the instruction set of ARM mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34818454/what-do-the-abbriviations-rn-rd-in-the-instruction-set-of-arm-mean)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Rd: Destination register
- Rn: An operand in a register for an arithmetic operation.
- Rm: An operand in a register for an arithmetic operation.
- Ra: A value in a register to be used in an addition or subtraction. 
  Think "accumulator"

You might take a pass through the [ARM Assembly Reference](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489g/Cihihggj.html) to see examples of these being used in this way.